# A reliable way to display google admanager ads in Flutter

Tags: flutter, ads, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I am struggling with trying to include ads from google admanager -aka DFP- (not admob).

I have found this package: "flutter_google_ad_manager 0.10.1" https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_google_ad_manager

However, digging into the package's code, it seems to use a PlatfromView that uses a native plugin to display ads on Android and iOS.

I found this comment on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12114 that discourages the use of PlatfromViews to display ads in flutter:

> "Note that because Flutter's AndroidView and UiKitView rely on
>   low-level manipulation of platform UI components, it's almost
>   guaranteed that they will interact with the Google Mobile Ads SDK in
>   ways the mobile ads engineering team have not anticipated and do not
>   test for. Even if the approach looks like it's working right now, it's
>   likely to run into issues with MRAID functionality, JS code included
>   in the creatives, and impression and click measurement. The last of
>   those is particularly important, since abnormalities in impression and
>   click stats can result in suspension of accounts.While we work on
>   these issues with the relevant parties we highly recommend using the
>   Flutter team's firebase_admob plugin, and discourage using plugins
>   that do use platform views to embed AdMob ads."

So, what should I do? Is there anyway to display DFP ads with flutter?

Comment: there is an official package which is not directly targeted for  Google Ad Manager but it does support it https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads